# val conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url:9001,hduser,hadoop123)

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

**:1: error: ')' expected but double literal found.** val conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url:9001,hduser,hadoop123)

val conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url:9001,hduser,hadoop123)
I am getting error when I am trying to connect hive server

Comment: `9001` is not a valid identifier for a type. You need to rename your type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `:9001`.

It expects a string but you are providing a variable name with a trailing `:9001` which throws a syntax error.

Try to concatenate the url with the string ":9001" instead.

Or declare the url like so:

```
url = "yoururlhere:9001"
```